# UpdatePanel postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm using UpdatePanel in my Modal, as you can see here:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
                    aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Telefones</h3>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <label>DDD (*):</label>
                                    <input id="txtDDD" runat="server" 
                                           class="form-control ddd"
                                           placeholder="DDD" 
                                           title="Insira o ddd do telefone"
                                           required="required" tabindex="3" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <label>Número (*):</label>
                                    <input id="txtNumeroTelefone" runat="server" 
                                           class="form-control numeroTelefone"
                                           placeholder="Número do Telefone"
                                           title="Insira o número do telefone"
                                           required="required" tabindex="3" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <label>Tipo (*):</label>
                                    <select id="ddlTipoTelefone" runat="server" 
                                            class="form-control" tabindex="2"
                                            title="Escolha o tipo do Telefone">
                                        <option value="Residencial">
                                                Residencial
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="Celular">Celular</option>
                                        <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
                                        <option value="Fax">Fax</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddTelefoneGrid" 
                                          EventName="click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddTelefoneGrid" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Adicionar" 
                        OnClick="btnAddTelefoneGrid_Click" />
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Fechar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that my button btnAddTelefoneGrid is firing a Postback causing the validation tag (required) to fire in the form behind my modal.

Im using Triggers to call code behind but it is not working. Please help!

Comment: Sorry did not understand the problem properly. What is not working? Shouldn't your click of btnAddTelefoneGrid button trigger the validation.

Comment: Sorry, i mean that my trigger is firing a postback, i can see that because i put a breakpoint on page_load, and because of this postback, my required fields behind my modal (in my main form) is triggering making me my trigger not hit the button's event on code behind. I removed every required tag in my aspx and it worked but i think there is another way to solve that because now i need to validate field by field with js. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood your problem properly. If you dont want the validation to trigger on click of btnAddTelefoneGrid you can set the property CausesValidation to false for this button. If you still need validation on click of the button but not for certain controls then you can use ValidationGroup property

Comment: Kiran Hegde, thanks!! That's exactly what i need. I'll use validationgroup for my required fields.